# How to send Ionic array to firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, arraylist

I have developed simple shopping cart. i am getting and displayed selected items successfully in html but need to store selected items (created as array) to firebase Database. I don't know how can I write selected items to firebase, if anyone knows kindly help me out.

This is my array.
[image]

cart.page.html

```
<form [formGroup]="createDataForm" (submit)="createData()">
<ion-list>

 <ion-grid><ion-row *ngFor="let item of selectedItems" lines="inset">
  <ion-col size="5"><div>{{ item.name }} - {{ item.price | currency:'USD':'symbol' }}</div></ion-col>
  <ion-col size="4.5">

  <ion-col size="2"><ion-label text-right> {{ (item.price * item.count) | currency:'USD':'symbol' }} 
   </ion-label></ion-col>
   </ion-row></ion-grid>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: firebase realtime database or firestore?

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: I am working on Firestore, welcome if any solution available on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
saveData(){
   let database = firebase.database();
   this.selectedItems.forEach((values) => {
     database.ref("shopping-cart").push(values);
   });
 }
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got a solution. given below

Note: It worked on firestore.

```
savedata() {
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
var db = firebase.firestore();
var n = this.selectedItems;
db.collection("myList").doc("MA").set({
n
})
.then(function() {
  console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

}